No ipv6 addresses on host machine, but apps in docker containers still try to listen on :: and get Errno 97 "Address family not supported by protocol"
I have a machine, that has no ipv6 addresses configured on any interface (including loopback). Moreover, /etc/hosts on the host machine does not contain ipv6 entries for "localhost".
However, there are some applications, that are run in docker containers that fail to start with an error socker.error [Errno 97] Address family not supported by protocol. I've narrowed it down to the following behaviour

the application makes essentially the following call: socket.getaddrinfo(None, 8080, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE | socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG)
it returns a bunch of addrinfos – (10, 1, 6, '', ('::', 8080, 0, 0)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('0.0.0.0', 8080)): the first entry is clearly an ipv6 version of "0.0.0.0"
the application attempts to bind to every returned address / port
fails when attempting to listen on ::, because, as I understand it, there are no interfaces with ipv6 address configured

Environment / restrictions:

applications are written in Python 2.7
I have no control over source code (ok, this is Python, so, technically, I have, – but still)
I do have control over how docker daemon is run, if it matters at all
I can reconfigure the network / OS on host machine, but the whole "no ipv6 on interfaces" business is out of my control
containers are run in network=host networking mode

Strangely, when I run python3 -c 'import socket; print(socket.getaddrinfo(None, 8080, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0, socket.AI_PASSIVE | socket.AI_ADDRCONFIG))' on host machine, I get back only this: [(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>, 6, '', ('0.0.0.0', 8080))], so no ipv6 addresses returned, but somehow inside the container the socket implementation thinks, that :: is available.
What can I do to make progress on this problem?
